# Converting code from objLoader2 to GLTFloader

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm having project which have built into threejs and laravel.
project is just working fine with **objLoader2** but large object files causing load timeout issues that's why client requirement is to convert code from **objLoader2 to GLTFLoader**

I just added reference of GLTFLoader to my project but it is causing parser errors for each loading object and output is blank.

**Added GLTFLoader reference like below in laravel:**

```
<script src="{{asset('js/GLTFLoader.js')}}"></script>
```

**Changed code objLoadercode2 like below:**

```
// instantiate a loader
for (var i = 0; i < options.pathLower.length; i++) {
  loadersLow[i] = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
}

for (var i = 0; i < options.pathUp.length; i++) {
  loadersUp[i] = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
}
```

**it's showing below errors after changing from new THREE.OBJLoader2() to new THREE.GLTFLoader()**

[image]

can anyone please guide me what I'm missing or is there any versioning conflicts?
any type of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Make sure to use all `three.js` files from the same release. Also keep in mind that a single instance of `GLTFLoader` is sufficient even when loading multiple assets.

Comment: Thank for your reply, you were correct!! Loading issues fixed now but not sure loaded model is showing up BLACK color. existing lighting effect not working which was with objloader2. Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: Sometimes this happens when the `metalness` value of your materials is `1` and the `roughness` is `0`. I suggest you flip both values if this is the case to fix the lighting issues.

Comment: @Mugen87 you are correct but I've tried flip values but no luck and object is still black here is the screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/aXSw1wIr2w